# Blockchain.info: Is there a way to know if a transaction is confirmed or not?

Tags: blockchain.info

I'm using the Blockchain.info API to get info about addresses and transactions.

It seems to me that the transactions (`txs`) don't indicate if they are confirmed or not.

Is there a way to get this info, directly from the api or indirectly, calculating the status from other values present in the repsonse?

Comment: I wouldn’t trust blockchain.info, they have quite the history of issues. But the good news is you can run your own node and easily query this information from it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rawtx` endpoint has a field `block_height`. If this field has an integer value, then the transaction was confirmed in the block at that height. If it is `null`, then the transaction is still unconfirmed. You can use that to know if a transaction is confirmed via the blockchain.info api.